# In SwiftUI for MacOS, How to make ignore mouse event for view?

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui, appkit

I got way to ignore mouse event for NSWindow. Surely It makes all window rect disable for mouse event.

[image]

I want to know ignore mouse event for NSView(part of window)

How can I make only red rect to ignore mouse event?

[image]

Comment: Are you saying you want mouse clicks and drags to pass through an opaque part of your window, and be received by some other app's window underneath yours?

Comment: @robmayoff Absolutely! Sorry for my little english

Comment: @Retriever Please, did you find a solution about this problem? I am also troubled by this

Comment: @BobXu I got the solution here 

https://www.reddit.com/r/SwiftUI/comments/k0yyy0/how_to_remove_the_maximize_button_on_macos/

Comment: @Retriever Thank you for your reply. However, from the url you gave, I still can't find how to make some of the views still respond to mouse events while using ignoresMouseEvents to make the window ignore all mouse events.

Comment: @BobXu Sorry... I thought you are looking for transparent title too. The solution for ignoreing cursor is here. Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct app1App: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .allowsHitTesting(false)
            Button("Ignore Mouse Events") {
                NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.accessory)
                for window in NSApplication.shared.windows {
                    window.isOpaque = false;
                    window.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear;
                    window.level = .floating
                    window.ignoresMouseEvents = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```